# Visible binding in KnockoutJS does not work properly?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a drop down box including 'dog', 'cat', 'bear'. I want to show an input box in front of the select box when the user select 'cat' or 'dog'. So I am using the visible binding to do this:

```html
<select data-bind="options:animals, value: animal"</select>
<input data-bind="value: description, visible: showDescription"/>
```

```js
self.showDescription=ko.observable(false);

self.showOtherDescription = function() {
   if(animal == 'cat' || animal == 'dog'){
     self.showDescription=ko.observable(true);
   }
}
```

It is working when the page is loaded. But when I change the option to 'bear' from the drop down it does not hide the input box. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: When posting, make sure your example code is a complete but minimal repro, and at the least syntactically correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to go IMO:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.animals = ['', 'cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'bird'];
  
  self.animal = ko.observable('');
  
  self.description = ko.observable('');

  self.showOtherDescription = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.animal() === 'cat' || self.animal() === 'dog';
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: animals, value: animal"></select>
<input data-bind="value: description, visible: showOtherDescription"/>
```

It changes / adds a few things to your code:

- The `showDescription` is not needed, at least not in the context of the things you've posted;
- The `showOtherDescription` needs to be a `computed` so it's updated when dependencies are updated;
- `showOtherDescription` should not have a "setter" function or side-effects that change other observables. If you do need such a setter, check out *writeable* computed observables;
- If you use `animal` as a two-way bound property, it needs to be an `observable` and thus needs to be invoked as a function to *get* its value.
- I'm not sure how the code you posted would work, as refer to `animal` like `animal == 'cat'` *as well* as use it in the View. I think it should probably be exposed publicly on the ViewModel, and as such you should refer to it as `self.animal`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are assigning to the observable instead of using observable function invocation in the "showOtherDescription" function , try this

```
//self.showDescription=ko.observable(true);
self.showDescription(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `showDescription` observable really should be the computed function to drive the visibility of the `<input>` element on the view:

```
self.showDescription = ko.computed(function(){
    return (animal() === 'cat' || animal() === 'dog');
});
```

Comment: Your code is working to show the input box. But my problem is when I change the option to 'bear' in the drop down, it does not hide the input box. How the input box knows that the option has been changed?

Comment: oh, I'm guessing that `animal` is also, an observable? I'll update my answer

Comment: without seeing more code or a working fiddle, there's not much else I can help with

Comment: @Jeroen you are right, I wanted to see it working before trying to optimize. Ideally, `showDescription` should be the computed function. I was trying to get what Sam had working first.

Comment: @Jeroen, I've updated my answer to use `showDescription` as the actual computed instead